# how to compile linux 0.01?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compiling, make

as i came across recompiling the linux kernel, i got a bit interested in the topic. so to go more deep and observe the output, i downloaded the linux kernel 0.01 from github (https://github.com/liudonghua123/linux-0.01). when i run `make` (with no extra parameters). i get errors:-

```
$ cd 'linux_kernel(0.01)-source_code'
$ make
gcc -Wall -O -fstrength-reduce -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-stack-protector  \
-nostdinc -Iinclude -c -o init/main.o init/main.c
In file included from include/sys/stat.h:5,
                 from include/unistd.h:53,
                 from init/main.c:2:
include/stdint.h:153: warning: "__INT64_C" redefined
  153 | #  define __INT64_C(c) c ## LL
      | 
<built-in>: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from include/sys/stat.h:5,
                 from include/unistd.h:53,
                 from init/main.c:2:
include/stdint.h:154: warning: "__UINT64_C" redefined
  154 | #  define __UINT64_C(c) c ## ULL
      | 
<built-in>: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from init/main.c:3:
include/time.h:39:8: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘strftime’; expected ‘long unsigned int(char *, long unsigned int,  const char *, const void *)’ [-Wbuiltin-declaration-mismatch]
   39 | size_t strftime(char * s, size_t smax, const char * fmt, const struct tm * tp);
      |        ^~~~~~~~
include/time.h:1:1: note: ‘strftime’ is declared in header ‘<time.h>’
  +++ |+#include <time.h>
    1 | #ifndef _TIME_H
init/main.c: In function ‘printf’:
init/main.c:114:45: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘vsprintf’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  114 |  write(1,printbuf,i=vsprintf(printbuf, fmt, args));
      |                                             ^~~~
      |                                             |
      |                                             va_list {aka char *}
init/main.c:38:12: note: expected ‘__va_list_tag *’ but argument is of type ‘va_list’ {aka ‘char *’}
   38 | extern int vsprintf();
      |            ^~~~~~~~
init/main.c: Assembler messages:
init/main.c:93: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
init/main.c:94: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
init/main.c:95: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `pushf'
init/main.c:96: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
init/main.c:97: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
make: *** [Makefile:27: init/main.o] Error 1
$
```

(i've copied the exact words from the shell)

how to fix?

Answer (score 5):

The 0.01 kernel can’t be built for 64-bit x86; on x86, you should target 32-bit instead. On top of that, recent linker changes mean that the code can’t be linked; we can fix that by allowing multiple definitions.

There are a couple of remaining issues, which can be fixed by editing `kernel/console.c` so that `columns` and `attr` are exported:

```c
static unsigned long lines=LINES;
unsigned long columns=COLUMNS;
static unsigned long state=0;
static unsigned long npar,par[NPAR];
static unsigned long ques=0;
unsigned char attr=0x07;
```

With that,

```
make CC="gcc -m32" AS="as --32" LD="ld -melf_i386 --allow-multiple-definition" clean Image
```

will complete successfully (assuming you have the appropriate GCC and binutils, and Bruce Evans’ `as86` and `ld86`), at least with GCC 10. I haven’t tried *booting* the resulting kernel; I’m not sure an ELF kernel will work at all.

Comment: error:-
ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `boot/head.o' is incompatible with i386 output
make: *** [Makefile:46: tools/system] Error 1

Comment: `boot/head.o` is a remnant from your previous attempts; you need to run `make clean`.

Comment: no, i think it is an error with linking the head.o file with something else. trying to solve it by myself.

Comment: can't solve. i give up (trying to solve it by MYSELF)... all i know about the error is that head.o file format might be 64 bit, so yeah.

Comment: Seriously, run `make clean` and run the build again. Running `make` produces a 64-bit `head.o`, and following up with a 32-bit build doesn’t touch it, resulting in the error you’re seeing. Running `make clean` removes it, and running the 32-bit build then produces a 32-bit `head.o` and everything links correctly.

Comment: no new results after changing everything to 32 bit and cleaning and again making...

Comment: You get the same `ld` error as in your first comment above? What command is used to build `head.o`? (It should be `as --32 -o boot/head.o boot/head.s`.)

Comment: It's probably easiest to find a set of installer floppy images for an early 1990s linux distro (like [MCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MCC_Interim_Linux) or [SLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softlanding_Linux_System)), install it in a 32-bit VM (you will probably need to set the CPU type to 486 because even Pentiums are probably too confusingly new-fangled for 0.01), and compile ancient kernels in that.

Answer (score 1):

Check this repo out where changes has been made to be able to compile on Ubuntu 18.04 64 and 32 bit versions. It also has a make command to run on qemu.
https://github.com/mariuz/linux-0.01